# How to search element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to replace image dynamically using jQuery and know how to replace image `src` value using jQuery.

But my main challenge is to find `<img>` tag and fetch its current value, since this HTML content is being displayed some some other API and that is not under my control. All I can add is an `id` attribute to external `div`.

This is current HTML structure being generated by the system:

```
<div id="mysection" class="span-20">
      <div class="row">
     <img src="/*/desktop/*/images/404.jpg">
     </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to find value of src and replace `desktop` with mobile, but I am not sure how I can find that using jQuery. All i know about find method of jQuery but not sure how to do that.

```
$( "#mysection" ).find( "src" ).attr('src');
```

is giving me undefined

Comment: `.find( "img" ).attr('src', "newURI")`

Comment: Why .find('src') ? Is there any element called src ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using img

```
$( "#mysection" ).find( "img" ).attr('src')
```

Answer (score 2):

To get img src value use:

```
var srcVal = $( "#mysection" ).find( "img" ).attr('src');
```

And to change desktop to mobile use:

```
$( "#mysection" ).find( "img").attr('src',srcVal.replace('desktop','mobile'));
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jfafA/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Dont search for `attr` search for element. You should use `img` selector. And use `replace()` to change the value from desktop to mobile

Try:

```
var src=$( "#mysection" ).find( "img" ).attr('src');
src=src.replace("desktop","mobile");
$( "#mysection" ).find( "img" ).attr('src',src);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/42sVZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$( "#mysection" ).find( "img" ).each(function(){
   var desktopSrc = $(this).attr('src');
   var mobileSrc = desktopSrc.replace("desktop","mobile");
   $(this).attr('src',mobileSrc);
});
```

It will find any img in #section element and replace desktop to mobile in each source attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `$( "#mysection" ).find( "img" ).attr('src')`.

Answer (score 0):

`.find(selector)` is used to find an element inside some element that matches `selector` (matching class, id, tag etc). The simplest thing to do in your case is to give your `img` an `id` and doing `$('#myImageId').attr('src');`

**EDIT**

I'm sorry I didn't notice that you cannot change the `img` attributes. In that case, `$('#mysection').find('img').attr('src');` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop( propertyName, function(index, oldPropertyValue) )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VC3ae/)</kbd>

```
$("#mysection").find("img").prop('src', function (_, old) {
    return old.replace("desktop", "mobile");
});
```

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#mysection img")
```

This will give you all `img` elements in your div. Once you grab that, you can itterate through them with `.each` and set the src.